# Python implementation of Multiple-Choice Knapsack

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have been searching for python implementation of multiple choice knapsack problem. So far I have found a java implementation in github: https://github.com/tmarinkovic/multiple-choice-knapsack-problem

And a psedu-code: http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter6.pdf

I have yet to find a python implementation. If there is a library implementing the multiple-choice knapsack problem I would be grateful to find out.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/USM-F/1287f512de4ffb2fb852e98be1ac271d Tried this one?